# How do I make a button to animate to margin-left: 50% on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I just have a simple button element, once a user hovers to it, I want to add margin-left property of 50%, but the problem is, I also want it to animate. I m on react.js. I tried using this:

```
      setStyles({
        animation: currentOption
      })
```

the string currentOption is a string which holds the keyframe name. but it doesen't work. how can I make it work?

Comment: Try to add property `transition: all ease 0.5s` on your button

Comment: The reason will may be you can't animate margin property. So try using transform-translate instead of margin

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the react button.

```
 <button class="my-button">Hover Me</button>
```

Styling can be given like this:

```
      .my-button {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
    }
    
    .my-button:hover {
      margin-left: 50%;
    }
```

This will solve the animation issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```css
        .button {
      margin-left: 0;
      transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
```

or

```css
 .button:hover {
  margin-left: 50%;
  animation: slideIn 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button:hover {
  margin-left: 50%;
  animation: slideIn 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Hi, please add explanations, or citations, so others can confirm that your answer is good. read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)